# Is there a way to automate pulling down multiple projects from a git repo using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

We used to use the working set configuration below, with subversion and the working set psf file would work... Visit the repository, pull down the source from that module, add the directory relative to the workspace and that is it.

Now I am not clear how converting to git would work to accomplish the same thing.

So we had a subversion based project working set configuration where we would use import project set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psf version="2.0">
<provider id="org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature">
    <project reference="1.0,http://repo.svn.com/svn/my-project/trunk,my-project"/>
</provider>
```

And the configuration above seemed to work as expected where the project was part of the workspace.  There was a .project at the root of the project and used configuration of that project.

If I use the git version, seems to do close but, things are off.  For example, it seems to use some git configuration default path when it pulls down the files (I am mac, uses ~/git).  May git configuration in git plugins.

But also, doesn't take the .project file from the root, in the example below, my-project has to be a sub directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psf version="2.0">
<provider id="org.eclipse.egit.core.GitProvider">
<project reference="1.0,https://git.mygithub.com/git/my-project,main,my-project"/>
</provider>
</psf>
```

Comment: Looks like it works if there is a sub directory.  Which is different format from svn to git.  Dont we put the dot project file at the root of the directory?

Comment: I didn't understand the issue completely. Can you tell what issue you are exactly facing?

Comment: I am using this script with Eclipse and working set, but doesn't work with a project where the .project files are at the root of a project.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psf version="2.0">
<provider id="org.eclipse.egit.core.GitProvider">
<project reference="1.0,https://git.mygithub.com/git/my-project,main,my-project"/>
</provider>
</psf>

For example:
How can I make this work with source with the following:

https://git.mygithub.com/git/my-project/.project

Comment: Ok got it. Looking into it.

Comment: Please add the directory tree of your setup and also add the .project contents. If the structure is my-project/my-project then you probably have a custom source folders setup not just pointing to `src`. DId you committed both .project and .classpath files?
Also, please explain what "but doesn't work" means.

Comment: You can do this and more with [Eclipse Oomph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring).

Comment: My package is this:

<repo>/.project
<repo>/src/main/java essetially

Comment: For oomph, do you have a more specific, detailed example

Comment: Also, are these project working set configs, really just doing a git clone or subversion svn co?  I could write a bash script.

Comment: There is a [tutorial for Eclipse Oomph here](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/oomph-basic-tutorial/). The idea of Eclipse Oomph is to setup up everything including the Eclipse IDE. If you only want to clone a collection of Git repositories, you can do this via [Git submodules](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cloning_Repositories_with_Submodules).